# Google results show a "For sale" button, how does this work

Tags: seo, google-search

I noticed that a "For sale" button appears when searching for a specific item. How does this work? I've been searching for answers but can't find much concrete information.

[image]

Comment: Haven't been able to replicate. Have you looked into those pages that show and seen any structured data? That is where I would start...